# Unable to get this patent ( number 75086) detail

Tags: prior-art, search

I am trying to look into the patent mentioned on this Art Deco: [Original années 1930 Betel motor car-art deco metal](https://www.ebay.fr/itm/202370752874?ViewItem=&item=202370752874). Ebay has sold many  in past bearing the same Patent number.

As can be seen the Patent number is 75086. I searched on [USPTO](http://pdfpiw.uspto.gov/.piw?Docid=75086&idkey=NONE&homeurl=http%3A%252F%252Fpatft.uspto.gov%252Fnetahtml%252FPTO%252Fpatimg.htm), [ESPACENET](https://worldwide.espacenet.com/searchResults?ST=singleline&locale=en_EP&submitted=true&DB=&query=75086&Submit=Search)  but could not locate any relevant Patent.

Is it a  design patent? Where can I get relvant details of this patent ?

[image]

Comment: Without a jurisdiction it is tough. I can tell for sure it isn't a US patent because the US patent of that number is unrelated:https://www.lens.org/images/patent/US/0075086/A/US_75086_A.pdf

Comment: It isn't a US design patent either: https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/fa/aa/ef/a3b98fe413af74/USD75086.pdf

Comment: I haven't found anything, but it seems they were around in 1930 so the number of jurisdictions seems limited. De, ch, nl, ca, us have patents in that number range before 1930, a few others too. Though one might have to plow through the patent offices and hope there are digital copies.

Comment: Is it beetle or betel? Volkswagen which owns beetle may be contacted in this regard.

Comment: 'BETEL' is a leaf chewed with nut and other ingredients especially in south Asia. Construction of the subject item and name suggests, primarily it was meant for storing betel and ingredients and the container was designed for easy passing on in a gathering. In this context seems 'BF' might stand for Britain Fabricated.

Comment: @ADAdhikary my research suggests it's a little toy car containing water colors.

Comment: I agree with DonQuiKong. If you follow the link it is clearly a cast metal toy car.

Comment: @DonQuiKong. I completely agree. Indeed it is a 'toy car' by look. I tried to establish its intended utility and country of manufacture. May be meant for 'water color'. But I just found some others  of the same or like genre being described as nut betel container using your key word 'toy car'. This is one of the links. https://www.indigo-uk.com/products/a4623. There are many more around. Seems the product type has gone viral in antique market.

Comment: Dear @ADAdhikary Thanks for your valuable info. But from where I can get patent? or do you think it is fake ?

Comment: @AbrarNoor. My assumption is,  some British inventor might have patented to cater to demand of  colonial India. British patent details are not available online for the period to which the number series belong . May be traced from British library. The other chance is Indian patent office and finding patent record of those time is a task to be avoided. Even if such a patent existed, possibility of some fake items can not be ruled out. Only experts can ascertain antiquity after physical verification. The market shows price range $59 to $ 75000. So buyers should take due care.